# Como Usar imagen de Background en una columna de Materialize

Tags: html, css, materialize

Buenas a todos, mi duda es como debo hacer para poner una imagen de background en una columna de materialize.

Por ejemplo supongamos que quiero una seccion con mitad una imagen y mitad un texto seria algo asi cierto ?

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col m6 imagen-aqui">

        </div>

        <div class="col m6">

        </div>
</div>
```

Entonces en el CSS hago algo asi

```
.imagen-aqui {

background-image: url('url o imagen');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

}

Pero no aparece nada :( que estoy haciendo mal ? o saben de alguna otra manera para separar una imagen grande con texto y titulos en un lado

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta poniendo esto en tu CSS:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 100vh;
```

Me parece que el problema se debe a que no has definido un alto para la imagen. Saludos

Comment: Me ha funcionado ! Muchas gracias te debo una :D